# Installing SC 9.0.2 with SIF and Remote Solr Server with Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework, certificate

I am Installing SC 9.0.2 with SIF and a Remote Solr Server with Self-Signed Certificate. i have split the script up as found here:

https://tothecore.sk/2018/04/19/installing-sitecore-9-xp0-with-solr-on-remote-server

Looks pretty dandy - but I am getting this message when running the Solr core install portion since the cert is self-signed:

[image: Error Messages from SIF]

Is there anyway around this? I know since I am running the cores portion on the solr box, I could just use localhost - but sitecore will not be able to access it because the connection is not trusted. I am using the IP address if the solr server because I don't have a DNS server. Any ideas besides getting a legit cert?

Comment: Wanted to clarify a few things. I went and regenerated the cert using a dns name of mysite.dev.com. I then added that to my hosts file on the solr server and of course removed the old certificate which was using "localhost" and replaced it with the new cert. I have also made sure to update the solr.ini.cmd file with the name of the new cert. Then restarted solr service. This has fixed the issue on the Solr Box. However, from the Sitecore box - it is still untrusted even though: hosts file matches cert dns, address matches cert dns and I have verified this in the browser by viewing cert info

Comment: Can you view the SOLR site in a chrome browser without issue?

Comment: You can see the answer I used below, but for other's sake - it persisted in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

The final piece to the puzzle was to make sure that I had the cert installed on my sitecore box as well - local machine > trusted root CA.

I realized that after I took a pass over this blog:

http://www.kurbegovic.com/blog/sitecore-9-multi-server-installation-part-2-solr-server-setup/

Thanks.